# Why ignore the custom size ProgressBar in android 4.4?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I have custom progressbar in my progect 
[image: progressBar]

the animation file custom_progress_bar.xml looks like this

[image]

anim1-anim20 - png files.

The problem is that when I run the project on Android 4.4 height and width of 240dp ignored and stretched to full width screen. If I run the project on Android 6.0 it looks fine. How to fix this problem?